# Teamroom template from Extension Library Error on all xpages after replacing design

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have taken an previous version Teamroom application and replaced the design of it with the teamroom tewmplateXL that is shipped with the extension library. In the notes client, the application functions fine, but every xpage returns the following error message. If I create a new application based on this template and then copy all of the documents to the new application they work fine.

```
Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
Script interpreter error, line=4, col=28: 'vc' is null
JavaScript code

   1: var teamname = strings.getString("teamroom.name");
   2: var vw:NotesView = database.getView("MissionLookup");
   3: var vc:NotesViewEntryCollection = vw.getAllEntries();
   4: var ve:NotesViewEntry = vc.getFirstEntry();
   5: if(null != ve){
   6:   var v:java.util.Vector = ve.getColumnValues();
   7:   if(!v.isEmpty()){
   8:       // get the teamroom name
   9:       teamname = v.get(1);
  10:   }
  11: }
  12: return teamname;
```

Comment: The obvious question, is there any entries in the "MissionLookup" view?

Comment: Yes there is an entry there

Comment: Is the Missionlookup view hidden in any way?
Have you tried to remove it in the old design before replacing the code?

Comment: The view is not hidden except for the () method of hiding from the client. I have not tried removing it and letting the template add it back in. I can try that. I am also going to try out the debugging toolbar I just ran across and see if / what that may ad to trouble shooting

Comment: Deleting the view and letting the replace design ad it back in did not rectify the issue either.